# Amazon EFS & Docker - Error when creating an image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I would like to use docker with amazon's elastic file system (EFS). So I mounted the EFS on the EC2 machine and set an efs-folder as the docker root folder in the docker config file. But when I want to create an image I get this error:

```
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
14.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
862a3e9af0ae: Extracting [==================================================>]      65.7 MB/65.7 MB
6498e51874bf: Download complete
159ebdd1959b: Download complete
0fdbedd3771a: Download complete
7a1f7116d1e3: Download complete
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): errno 524
```

In the docker logs I get this error:

```
Error trying v2 registry: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): errno 524
Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): errno 524
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding `-s devicemapper` to the `docker daemon`command as described in an issue: [New Docker versions cannot host datastore on NFS share](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15239)

Comment: Do you still use that solution? Have you had any issues when running several EC2 instances sharing the same EFS directory?